# System Sound plays very quietly over speakers - C, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, audio

I'm using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound in Objective-C to play my sound effects. They play perfectly loud on simulator and on my iPad's speakers, but when I plug an audio cord from my iPad into a speaker, the sound is ridiculously low, barely audible. I've tried different speakers and got the same effect. Over bluetooth the sound is still quiet but at least audible. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"MySoundEffect.caf"];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path isDirectory: NO];
    NSLog(@"filepath = %@", filePath);

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: Don't abuse format strings for constructing path names. `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySoundEffect" ofType:@"caf"]` should be good enough.

Comment: Simple question: do the speakers have an in-built amplifier?  *ie* are they powered?  Do they produce a normal volume when you plug them into a different device?  Sounds like you are trying to drive speakers directly from a line-level output.

Comment: Or the iPad's headphone volume is just set really low…

Comment: @H2CO3 Abusing the format strings is irrelevant to this problem, as the sound works and I've tried the "ofType" format before and had the same problem.

Comment: @paddy Yes the speakers are powered, and produce normal volume when playing mp3s, but when I try system sounds the volume is very low only for the system sounds, mp3s in the same app play normal volume.

Comment: @duskwuff Is there a separate volume setting for headphones? If so I can't find it.

Comment: @fiorgodx: Yes. Once the speakers are plugged in, press the volume up button a few times.

Comment: @fiorgodx I know, it was just a sidenote...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with simply using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound. My workaround was to use SimpleAudioEngine which does some work behind the scenes that I assume keep the audio volume and quality intact even when playing over bluetooth or line in.